# When searching a drop down list is it possible to bring the result to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

On my page I've got a `select` list with over 100 options in it and I wanted to know if it was possible that when a user enters a character say 's' that the list brings the first s result to the top of the drop down window?

Currently the default behaviour is to bring the first s result to the very bottom of the window.

In this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L51g7po0/3/) you can see that typing a letter say 'p' brings it to the bottom of the window. Where as I want it to be brought to the top, or as high as possible if there aren't enough results to fill the window.

Comment: please provide your code that  you have tried

Comment: There a lot libraries that handle the job you want like [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: Its not at the bottom it is bringing by default it is showing the index where it  is present type some other letter you will get what I mean..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1):

To program  this functionality yourself is probably not worth the effort. Instead I would recommend using an existing library:

- [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
- [Select 2](https://select2.github.io/)

Here is example code from the Select 2 documentation. The functionality you are looking for will come right out of the box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
```

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option>...</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {});
function filterItems(thisobj) {  
  var removedOption = $("select option").filter(function(i) {
    return ($(this).text().search($(thisobj).val()) < 0);
  }).remove();
  $("select").append(removedOption);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onchange="filterItems(this);" />
<select>
  <option value="1">ankit</option>
  <option value="">parth</option>
  <option value="">bhavik</option>
  <option value="">dilip</option>
  <option value="">tejas</option>
  <option value="">Zibra</option>
  <option value="">jon</option>
  <option value="">mak</option>
  <option value="">swati</option>
  <option value="2">niks</option>
  <option value="3">sids</option>
  <option value="4">mans</option>
  <option value="5">mit</option>
  <option value="6">vipul</option>
</select>
```

Comment: May be a closest answer.